# Water barely comes out of my kitchen tap, then stops

Tags: water

When I turn on the water faucet in the kitchen sink, the water barely comes out then stops. If I wait about an hour, it does same thing again. If I turn the faucet on in the upstairs bathroom, no water comes out. I have city water. It does sound like there is air in the lines. You can hear it like when the water is turned off then comes back on.

Comment: Is it just the kitchen that isn't working? Do any other taps (toilets, bath, shower) in the house work? Both hot and cold? If so, have you tried taking off the aeration screen (it just unscrews)?

Comment: sounds like you got frozen pipes, with the area before the kitchen sink being a little warmer, allowing some water to thaw and build up.

Comment: @dandavis - you might be right as to frozen pipes but as to kitchen being warmer - based on ops writing kitchen is not upstairs bath is ; op has no water pressure building up to flow upstairs - barely running in kitchen and stops seems plausible not enough WP.

Comment: My strainer in the faucet needs to be cleaned out about once a year.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have any recent work performed on either the pipes, a hot water heater added, an Aqua therm unit installed  ?
Where are you located in the world ?

If so you might just have a piece of garbage in the aerators - at each faucet remove the aerators (thing at bottom of faucet outlet where water comes out you can unscrew it by hand usually) and then turn the water on. Then reinstall the aerators onto the faucets and test.
If you have copper pipes and sweating of copper joints was done - this is a very likely possibility.

Also as one commenter pointed out - frozen pipes ? - Both Hot and Cold ?

Comment: If it's a 2 handle 1 faucet job, or one of those single handle, adjust for temp and pressure, there's probably a mixer cartridge under the faucet itself. These can get load up with junk and stop water flow as you describe.